# Model binds only if I remove [FromForm] attribute from parameter in .NET Core API

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I am trying to post FormData using ajax to my API, but for some reason, it only binds properly if I remove the [FromForm] attribute from my endpoint.

Endpoint:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostData([FromForm] psVM model)
{
   // Inspecting model after setting breakpoint here shows that it didn't bind properly.
}
```

Model:

```
public class psVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Document { get; set; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="submitForm">
    <input type="file" id="upload" name="Document" accept=".pdf">
</form>
```

JS/Ajax post:

```
var data = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("submitForm"));
data.append("Id", 1);

$.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    data: data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 600000,
    type: 'post',
    error: function(e) {
        ...
    },
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: And what's the problem with removing the 'FromForm' attribute?

Comment: Just trying to understand why it doesn't work with it.

Comment: Why don't you just used `FromBody`?

Comment: Because I am trying to post a file.